# Solving System of Equations where the Variables are Array References

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

New to MMA.  I am trying to solve equations where the unknown variables are array references $a[x]$ and the known coefficients are obtained by evaluating the value of functions at points $idirt[x,t]$ and $itime[x,t]$:

```
t = 6
xn3 = Table[idirt[X, t] == -a[X]*itime[X, t], {X, 75, 70, -1}]
Solve[{xn3}, {a[75], a[74], a[73], a[72], a[71], a[70]}]
```

I receive the error:

```
"is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities."
```

Additionally, is there a way to specify a range of array values to solve for $a[70-75]$, or do they need to all be written out like I have done?

Comment: `Solve[xn3,...']` should work, i.e. drop the `{}` around `xn3`. You can specify variables with e.g. `Map[a, Range[70, 75]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `a[x]` is not an array reference but rather an indexed variable. References to part of an array or vector are done with [`Part ([[...]])`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
t = 6;

var = a /@ Range[70, 75];

xn3 = Table[idirt[X, t] == -a[X]*itime[X, t], {X, 70, 75}];

soln = Solve[xn3, var]
```

> $\{{a[70] -> -(idirt[70, 6]/
>             itime[70, 6]), a[71] -> 
>        -(idirt[71, 6]/itime[71, 6]), 
>      a[72] -> -(idirt[72, 6]/
>             itime[72, 6]), a[73] -> 
>        -(idirt[73, 6]/itime[73, 6]), 
>      a[74] -> -(idirt[74, 6]/
>             itime[74, 6]), a[75] -> 
>        -(idirt[75, 6]/itime[75, 6])}\}$

```
values = var /. soln[[1]]
```

> $\{-(idirt[70, 6]/itime[70, 6]), 
>    -(idirt[71, 6]/itime[71, 6]), 
>    -(idirt[72, 6]/itime[72, 6]), 
>    -(idirt[73, 6]/itime[73, 6]), 
>    -(idirt[74, 6]/itime[74, 6]), 
>    -(idirt[75, 6]/itime[75, 6])\}$

Comment: Thanks!  I am now trying to store these solutions as values rather than rules via /. but am having issues:

    sol3 = Solve[xn3, var]
    solutions[var] = sol3[[1]]